# CSH - How to check if input is NOT number

Tags: shell-script, csh

Need to apply it on csh.

to check if the inputted `$2` is not number nor the word "all"

```csh
if ($#argv == 2 && ($2 != all && $2 != **any number**)) then
   echo "wrong parameter"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( $#argv == 2 && $2 != 'all' && $2 !~ ^[0-9]+$ ) then
   echo "wrong parameter"
endif
```

Tested on AIX 7.1 - CSH 1.20.3.5

Comment: Is that supposed to be `$#argv` and not just `$argv`?

Comment: $argv returns all the arguments, whereas $#argv returns the number of arguments

Comment: Ahh, so that's a csh-specific thing then. Good to know!

Comment: what is the difference between the one with the + and *? `^[0-9]+$` and `^[0-9]*$`?

Comment: '+' means 1 or more. '*' means 0 or more. The latter will match an empty string.